# Use Cnodb but failed to insert table

Tags: cnosdb

Version: cnosdb 2.3.2, revision ffeeadf37340d011eab8ecf5a8c1afbd54a98d48

cnosdb-cli

```
CREATE TENANT tenant_a;
CREATE USER user_a;
ALTER TENANT tenant_a ADD USER user_a AS owner;
```

cnosdb-cli -u user_a -t tenant_a:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_a;
\c db_a
CREATE TABLE air_a (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air_a (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69, 77);
```

cnosdb_cli:

```
DROP TENANT IF EXISTS tenant_a;
DROP USER IF EXISTS user_a;
CREATE TENANT tenant_a;
CREATE USER user_a;
ALTER TENANT tenant_a ADD USER user_a AS owner;
```

cnosdb-cli -u user_a -t tenant_a:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_a;
\c db_a
CREATE TABLE air_a (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air_a (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69, 77);
```

Show error:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"020004","error_message":"DataSchemaError: database 'db_a' not found"}
```